# Recover on Akka ask based on the message sent

Tags: scala, akka, future, actor, akka-stream

I am sending different messages to the actor via `ask`. On timeout I'd like to provide a default value which is different for messages being asked to the actor.

Since the Timeout Exception is always the same, I can not use it in `recover` to return different default values I need the original message being sent.

How can one achieve that.

Code example:

```scala
      val storageActorProxy = Flow[ByteString]
        .via(Framing.lengthField(TCPMessage.sizeFieldLength, TCPMessage.sizeFieldIndex, Int.MaxValue))
        .map(TCPMessage.decode)
        .ask[OperationResponse](storageActor)
        //TODO: looking for this recover; non-existent AFAIK
        .customRecover { 
            case Op1 => DefaultResponseA()
            case Op2 => DefaultResponseB()
        }
        .map(TCPMessage.encode(_).toByteString)
```

Comment: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-error.html#errors-from-mapasync - try `.withAttributes(supervisionStrategy(resumingDecider)))`

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok but resuming decider just "The element is dropped and the stream continues.", which is not what I need, I do not want to drop it, but to provide a default value (basically map the sent operation to the default value) if the response is not received

Comment: Then you shouldn't' use `flow.ask` but `flow.mapAsync` and handle `Future` recovery inside of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Akka's `ask` method is actually pretty easy to recreate - it is just a `mapAsync` with some extra logic for better errors when the actor dies ([see the code](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/0e4d41ad33dbeb00b598cb75b4d29899371bdc8c/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/Flow.scala#L1100-L1121)). As such, just use `mapAsync` manually so you can recover the ask error.

```scala
val storageActorProxy = Flow[ByteString]
  .via(Framing.lengthField(TCPMessage.sizeFieldLength, TCPMessage.sizeFieldIndex, Int.MaxValue))
  .map(TCPMessage.decode)
  .mapAsync(parallelism = 2) { decodedMessage =>
     (storageActor ? decodedMessage).recover {
       case Op1 => DefaultResponseA()
       case Op2 => DefaultResponseB()
     }
  }
  .map(TCPMessage.encode(_).toByteString)
```